# async/await display data in global scope

Tags: javascript, mongoose, async-await, es6-promise

This is my first time using promises and mongoose, and I'm trying to save data to global variable for later  use

```
const getUser = async () => {
    let user 
    try {
       user = await clientModel.findOne({username: email})
       consoe.log(user) 
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    return  user
  }

  const filteredUser = getUser().then((value) => {
    return value
  }).catch((e) => console.log(e));

  console.log(filteredUser)
```

user console log displays content:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61aa75c64e1526131d98f2a1"),
  username: 'paul@beatles.uk',
  chequing: null,
  saving: '1000022',
  __v: 0
}
```

but filteredUser keeps displaying `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: All `async` functions return a promise.  The caller must use `await` or `.then()` to get the value from that promise.  See [Why do I need to await an async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895695/why-do-i-need-to-await-an-async-function-when-it-is-not-supposedly-returning-a-p/56895719#56895719) for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve promise for use data. Read about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

It can be await or then