# Why does reduce waits for promises sequentially, while forEach does not?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Consider the code:

```js
const promises = [
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000, "Hi")),
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500, "second")),
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100, "third"))
];
promises.reduce(async(a, promise) => {
  await a;
  const p = await promise;
  console.log(p);
}, Promise.resolve());
```

The output of this code is Hi, first, third, despite there is a massive time difference between these three promises.
My thoughts:

In each iteration, the reduce callback returns immediately with a pending promise which resolves synchronously. Therefore, its subsequent async opeerations will wait until the three promises returned by the callback is resolved. But I still don't think the output should be like this, because those three promises are separate ones - each one creating its own chain of async operation. When the first callback executes, the function immediately resolves with undefined. Then, the async code (the awaiting of promises and the logging of three is defered to the next event cycle - placed into the microtask queue). I think this happens to all three of the promises iterated by reduce.

However, in a forEach loop, the promises are resolved insequentially, even with the following code:

```js
const promises = [
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000, "Hi")),
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500, "second")),
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100, "third"))
];
promises.forEach(async promise => {
  // try to force the delay of the "promise" in the promises array.
  await 3;
  const p = await promise;
  console.log(p);
});
```

The output is second, third, first. Why is this happening?

So why did this happen? I totally expeected someething different

Comment: `await 3` does nothing…

Comment: Why you say "*the reduce callback returns immediately with a pending promise which resolves synchronously*"?

Comment: In `reduce`, the `a` is the result of the previous function call. An `async` function results in a promise. So `await a` is explicitly awaiting the result of the previous iteration. — No such interdependent linkage in `forEach` loops.

Comment: "*Why does reduce waits for promises*" - it doesn't. `await a;` does.

Comment: @Bergi, because of the await keyword. I thought that await pauses the function, pushes the code after the await keyword after it into a queue. This allows the JS engine to be freed to execute other things which is the reason why I said the callback function returns a pending promise immediately.

Comment: @TobyHarnish Sorry, I should have been more specific: I'm taking issue with "*which resolves synchronously*". The promise doesn't resolve until the execution of the function (with all the asynchronous `await`s) completes

Comment: Plus, [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895695/why-do-i-need-to-await-an-async-function-when-it-is-not-supposedly-returning-a-p/56895719?noredirect=1#comment137303721_56895719) confirms that.

Comment: @Bergi, I mean, in the first iteration, the Promise.resolve() resolves synchronously right? Also, in subsequent iterations, the pending promise returned by the async callback also resolves immediately, because all the promises inside the array is delayed to the next event cycle. Maybe I am wrong at my reasoning?

Comment: Btw have a look at [array .reduce having issues with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41243468/1048572) to see what would happen when you omit `await`ing the accumulator. It's still `reduce` waiting for promises, it just doesn't work. So the behaviour you are observing is not an intrinsic property of `reduce`.

Comment: @Bergi, what do you mean I don't "await" thee accumulator? That is what await a is doing.

Comment: @TobyHarnish What do you mean by "*all the promises inside the array is delayed to the next event cycle*"? No, the promises returned by the `async` callback do not resolve immediately. They only resolve after the `await a` and the `await promise` have taken their time.

Comment: @Bergi, I mean the "await a" is resolved synchronously. However, the async operation after that is not - they are queued for in the future.

Comment: @TobyHarnish Well in the very first iteration, where `a` is the already-fulfilled `Promise.resolve()`, it continues immediately indeed. But in the second iteration, `a` is the promise returned by the first callback execution, which is not resolved immediately.

Comment: @Bergi, then when will it be resolved? If I understood this correctly, the callback just returns a pending promise which will be resolved with the valuee of undefined anyway. It's not waiting for anything.

Comment: @TobyHarnish "*It's not waiting for anything*" - sure does: `const p = await promise;`

Comment: @Bergi, I thought that this line is being defered to the next event cycle, because all code after the await keyword is pushed to the queue for future execution?

Comment: @TobyHarnish The "*code after the await keyword*" includes the part where the promise is resolved (or rejected, if the code were to throw an exception). It cannot know yet that the promise will be resolved with `undefined`, the code may `return` something else from the async function.

Comment: @Bergi, So are you saying that in the line "const p = await promise;" --the promise is also defered its resolution?

Comment: @TobyHarnish Sure, *every* (executed) line with `await` defers the resolution of the promise returned by the `async` function

Comment: @Bergi, Please be patient with me:) So, every async function's promise (the promise returned by the async function) is not resolved until all of its awaited promises are resolved?

Comment: @TobyHarnish Yes, exactly. Just consider the common case of `return`ing a value from the async code.

Comment: @Bergi, Is it correct to say that the reactionary handlers are added asynchronously for each promise in the array?

Comment: @TobyHarnish Yes

Comment: @Bergi, In this [post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), it give an example where you can pass a primitive value as handlers. I do not understand why that works and why it does not throw an error. Can you explain why, because it does not really explain it.

Comment: @TobyHarnish `then` simply ignores any handler that is not a function. I wouldn't say it "works". But I don't see what this has to do with `reduce`, I recommend you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Bergi, I know it does not really relate to promises in reduce, but my questions aren't received by the "experts" here. In fact, recently I have asked a question on what part of JS engine resolves the promise returned by fetch, and it was closed and even removed by the community:) I don't know what else to do. Hopefully you can help me understand promises deeper. I do thankyou for the amount of patience and time though.

Comment: @TobyHarnish Can you share a link? (I can't see it [when searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A19104772+is%3Aquestion+deleted%3Ayes), you can) Questions usually don't get removed for no reason.

Comment: @Bergi, sure:) [The post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77385849/does-the-fetch-apis-c-code-resolves-the-promise-when-a-response-is-obtained?noredirect=1#comment136435722_77385849). I think it is closed as "not focussed" - I don't really know what they mean by "not focussed".

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for confirming. I do not have anyone that I can ask these questions to. I only post my question if I am very desbrate for an answer.

Comment: @TobyHarnish Next time you ask a promise-related question, ping me here and I'll take a look

Comment: @Bergi, I have asked this [new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77977579/passing-a-primitive-to-a-then-handler). Hopefully it doesn't get deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that with the forEach case, you're making 3 short promise chains, while with the reducer case you're making 1 long complicated chain. The 3 short chains are only waiting on their original promise each, but the long chain, via the code `await a`, is waiting for each previous iteration to finish before resuming.

Now on to the nitty gritty details.

```
const promises = [
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000, "Hi")),
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500, "second")),
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100, "third"))
];
```

First, I'll point out that these lines of code start the timeouts *immediately*. So regardless of what happens later, the timers will always go off at the 100ms, 500ms, and 10000ms marks (plus or minus the usual innacuracy of timers). The `await`s decide what you want to pause for, but they don't affect when the original 3 promises resolve.

With that in mind, let's look at the foreach case since it's simplest. I'll get rid of the `await 3` since that does very little.

```
promises.forEach(async promise => {
  const p = await promise;
  console.log(p);
});
```

Your function first gets called with the 10000ms promise. You await the 10000 ms promise, which causes your function to return a promise of its own. `.forEach` doesn't care what you return, so it moves on to the next element in the array, which is the 500ms promise. You await the 500 ms promise and return. Then same thing with the 100ms promise.

After 100 ms, that original promise resolves. This means that the 3rd instance of your function can now resume, logging out third. At the 500ms mark, that original promise resolves, allowing the 2nd instance of the function to resume. And finally at the 10000ms mark, the first instance of the function can resume.

---

And now let's turn our attention to the reducer case.

```
promises.reduce(async (a, promise) => {
  await a;
  const p = await promise;
  console.log(p);
}, Promise.resolve());
```

On the first iteration, `a` is the promise from `Promise.resolve()`, and `promise` is the 10000ms promise. You await `a`, causing your function to return a new promise. Reduce doesn't pay attention to the promise, except to blindly pass it on to the next iteration.

We now enter the second iteration, with `a` being the promise returned by the first iteration, and `promise` being the 500ms promise. The second iteration awaits `a`. Since `a` is the first iteration's promise this set up a chain where this second function has to wait for the first function to resolve its promise. The 2nd iteration returns a promise, which gets passed to the third iteration, which does a similar await.

Now that we've finished the synchronous code, a microtask gets queued and the first function resumes after its `await a`. The first function moves on to the next line and `await`s `promise`, which is the 10000ms promise. The function pauses execution at this point.

A bit later, the 100ms promise resolves. Nothing is directly awaiting it, so nothing happens at this point. Later still, the 500ms promise resolves. Again, nothing is directly awaiting it. And even later, the 10000ms promise resolves. This allows the first function to resume. It logs "hi", then returns, thus resolving its own promise. Because it resolved its promise, function 2 (which was patiently sitting on `await a`) can now resume. function 2 then awaits `promise`, which is the 500ms promise. This promise is already resolved, so after the briefest of interruptions it resumes, logs "second" and returns. This in turn unlocks function 3, which awaits `promise` (the 100ms one), then resumes. It logs out "third" and is done.

Comment: Can you add something like "*`.reduce` doesn't care what you return, either*" (it just passes the value into the next iteration's call) to clarify this is not caused by `reduce` itself?

Comment: Good sugestion, done.

Comment: The answer could do with a TL;DR -- the essential difference is that `await a` serializes the `reduce` version. Remove that and you get the same result as `forEach`

Comment: @Nicholas Tower, can you also explain why await 3 doesn't do anything in forEach?

Comment: Well, it does do a bit, but nothing that changes the result. In short: When `await 3` executes, the function returns (as is normal for the `await` keyword). Since the thing we're awaiting is not a promise, a microtask immediately gets queued up to resume the function. Then once the synchronous code finishes, that microtask will run and move on to the `await promise` line, which is the part that really matters, since it will result in an actual delay.

Comment: @NicholasTower, "A bit later, the 100ms promise resolves" - I don't think so, because in order for the 100 ms promise to be resolved, the 10000 ms one have to resolve first so that it will in terms resolve the promise returned by the 100 ms async callback. The 100 ms callback have to wait its resolution until the promise returned by the 10000 ms resolves. My reasoning is inspired by Bergi

Comment: `I don't think so, because in order for the 100 ms promise to be resolved, the 10000 ms one have to resolve first` You started the 100ms timeout on this line: `new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100, "third"))`.100 ms after that line executes (plus or minus a bit of variance), `r` gets called, resolving the promise.

Comment: @Nicholas Tower, Okay, I think I understand now. So the 100 ms promise resolves first, but there is no "handler" to execute it. So, when the 10000 ms promise resolves, the 500 and 100 ms promiss are already resolved. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct