# Passing a primitive to a then handler

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer, asynchronous-javascript

This is an interesting observation that I have made when experimenting with promises in JS. Consider this code:

```js
Promise.resolve(1).then(2).then(console.log);
```

This prints out 1 as its output. Why didn't the native-implemented promise API throw an exception? What is the benefit of "skipping" the non-function argument when it is being ignored anyway? I woud really apreciate an answer

This post is found in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? Something like "because the spec says so", perhaps with a link to the spot in the spec? Or are you looking for the motivations of the people that wrote the spec?

Comment: @Nicholas Tower, I want to know what is the point of not throwing an exception since it is not needed anyway. Wouldn't it be a good thing for the programmers to be at least informed of?

Comment: @TobyHarnish programmers *are* informed, because it's specified behavior.

Comment: @TobyHarnish You already said it, "*it is not needed anyway*", so why should it throw? An exception would mean to **not** ignore the argument.

Comment: @Bergi, But why do you get an exception when you do not supply a function to the promise constructor? Why couldn't the native implementation just "ignore" it?

Comment: a) because the `Promise` constructor is not part of the Promises/A+ interoperability b) because the executor is absolutely necessary to create a promise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way modern promises work is defined by the [ECMAScript spec](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/). But promises already existed before they were added as a core part of the language, so for backwards compatibility they were designed to match the behavior of community-built promises. The spec that was used by the community is called [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/), and the relevant part is this:

> 2.2 The `then` method
>
> A promise’s then method accepts two arguments:
> `promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`
>
> 2.2.1 Both onFulfilled and onRejected are optional arguments:
> 2.2.1.1 **If onFulfilled is not a function, it must be ignored.**
> 2.2.1.2 If onRejected is not a function, it must be ignored.

ECMAScript has inherited that behavior in its spec. That spec is much harder to read, but i think it's this part from [PerformPromiseThen](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/?_gl=1*ck3a8n*_ga*MjUwNDUzMjM4LjE3MDc2NzA2ODU.*_ga_TDCK4DWEPP*MTcwNzY3MDY4NS4xLjAuMTcwNzY3MDY4NS4wLjAuMA..#sec-performpromisethen)

> 3. If IsCallable(onFulfilled) is false, then
>    a. Let onFulfilledJobCallback be empty.

As for why they chose to design them this way, I don't know.

Comment: "*why they chose to design them this way*" - to make them optional. `.then(handler, undefined)` and `.then(undefined, handler)` (better known as `.catch`) are *useful* (or even necessary), and it's no stretch to allow things like `.then(null, null)`. Sure, one could have specified throwing an error when receiving some other primitive value or non-callable object, but that goes against the general design principles of JS and would make the API less future-proof and backwards-compatible. Also it's not the point of an interoperability API, which was the entire premise of Promises/A+.